# Python makes additional folder

Tags: python, group-by, path

I have a simple question, but cant really solve that. I have the following code in groupby loop. for each file, python makes the folders \user\Desktop\CO\Sites on my destination folder, but I just want to find the path and put my zip file on that path, not making that again. 
Can you please advise?

for n,g in groupby:

```
    csv=g.to_csv(index=False)

    filename = '{}{}'.format(r'C:/Users/Desktop/CO/Sites/Site_',n)

    os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Desktop')

    filename_csv = filename + '_Co_'+ '.csv'

    filename_zip = filename + '_Co_' +'.zip'

    with open(filename_csv,'w') as out_file:

        out_file.write(csv)

    zip_all_zips.append(filename_zip)

    zip_all_csvs.append(filename_csv)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can check if the directory is present, otherwise create it:

```
if not os.path.exists("filepath/"):
```

Comment: Thank you, Can you please advise where should I put it ?

Comment: Can you please advise?

Comment: Place it before you create the filename, then the directory will always be present. Maybe you also can look into os.path module